# Is it possible to get the code from IntelliJ's SwingUI designer?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA's SwingUI Designer to create a couple of simple GUIs, but when using the .form files, the GUI generation code appears to be stored in XML format. Is it possible to somehow view the actual Java code that is being used to generate the GUIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | [GUI Designer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gui-designer.html) | Generate GUI into: **Java source code** option. Then on build IDE will auto generate the source code for forms. Note that you should not change this code manually.